# Index out of range exception in FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal when running SqlQuery EF

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, azure-application-insights

We are getting eventually an **IndexOutOfRange** exception when running code like this:

```
result.Data = dbOptima.Database.ExecuteStoredProcedure(
    task,
    StoredProcedureValues.PROC_GET_TASKS).ToList();
```

,where `ExecuteStoredProcedure` does the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> ExecuteStoredProcedure<TResult>(this Database database, IStoredProcedure<TResult> procedure, string procedureName)
{
    var parameters = CreateSqlParametersFromProperties(procedure);
    var format = CreateSPCommand<TResult>(parameters, procedureName);

    return database.SqlQuery<TResult>(format, parameters.Cast<object>).ToArray());
}
```

We cannot reproduce the problem locally, but using **Application Insights** the exception is registered quite often. The following is a call stack extract:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException:
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal (System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal (System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.TryGetColumnOrdinalFromReader (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.CreateColumnMapFromReaderAndClrType (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.InternalTranslate (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext+<>c__DisplayClass65`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__64 (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext+<>c__DisplayClass65`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__63 (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute (EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryReliably (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext (EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList (System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089)
```

We've tried to reproduce the problem locally by:

- making the stored procedure fail.
- making the stored procedure return 0 results.
- causing a mapping problem by renaming some model property.

with no success.

Typically, this error happens due to a mapping error in the **datareader** when you use **ADO.NET**, but this is not the case since we use **EF 6** and it does not happen always, so we cannot really find where the problem is.

Comment: Running into a similar issue; did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is related to binding the **result** of the stored procedure with the **model** declared to be bound with the output of the stored procedure.

If the stored procedure retrieves more columns than the properties that the model has, even though the model is satisfied (because all the properties can be matched with columns of the stored procedure output), internally an exception is raised cause the model doesn't have properties to store some of the store procedure output values.

So, this can be fixed in two ways: either

- adding properties in the model to contain the columns of the stored
  procedure, or
- removing the unnecessary columns of the stored procedure output.

The second approach is normally better, since this issue is making evident that some data returned by the stored procedure is no longer required, so it would be cleaner and more performant to remove the unneeded code in the stored procedure.

Comment: I have properties for all columns returned from the stored proc. It seems this exception is also thrown when there are properties in the receiving class that are not mapped to a column returned from the stored proc.

Comment: I asked a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65753462/how-do-i-include-a-notmapped-property-in-an-ef-business-object-without-getting