# How do I include a [NotMapped] property in an EF business object without getting FirstChance IndexOutofRangeException?

Tags: entity-framework-6, xaf

I was wondering why my XAF WinForms EF application was slow loading a detail view.
Then I learned how to capture FirstChance Exceptions and discovered I was experiencing an IndexOutOfRange exception as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143207/index-out-of-range-exception-in-fieldnamelookup-getordinal-when-running-sqlquery)

Sometimes I want to include a non mapped property in my business object such as Job in example.

```
  public class OrderLineResult  
    {
        public int LineId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Browsable(false)] public int JobId { get; set; }
        [NotMapped] [Browsable(false)] public virtual Job Job { get; set; } 
    }
```

And I have a method to get the data inside the OrderLineResult class

```
public static OrderLineResult[] GetData(int headId)
    {
        using var connect = new MyDbContext()
            const string sql =
            @"SET NOCOUNT ON;
            create table #temp( JobId int, Quantity int,  LineId int, Description   )
            /* code to populate the table */
            select JobId,LineId,Quantity, Description  from #temp"
            var results = connect.Database.SqlQuery<OrderLineResult>(sql,headId).ToArray();
            return results.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Yet the IndexOutOfRange exception occurs for the Job property.

The call stack is

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException
Job
   at MyApp.Module.Win.Controllers.ToDoList.TaskActionController.<>c.<actExceptions_Execute>b__34_0(Object sender, FirstChanceExceptionEventArgs e)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.TryGetColumnOrdinalFromReader(DbDataReader storeDataReader, String columnName, Int32& ordinal)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ColumnMapFactory.CreateColumnMapFromReaderAndClrType(DbDataReader reader, Type type, MetadataWorkspace workspace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.InternalTranslate[TElement](DbDataReader reader, String entitySetName, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, EntitySet& entitySet, TypeUsage& edmType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryInternal[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass186_0`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__1()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.<>c__DisplayClass186_0`1.<ExecuteStoreQueryReliably>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQueryReliably[TElement](String commandText, String entitySetName, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery[TElement](String commandText, ExecutionOptions executionOptions, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at MyApp.Module.BusinessObjects.NonPersistedBusinessObjects.OrderLineResult.GetData(Int32 headId)
```

I am using EntityFramework 6.4.4      and .Net Framework 4.7.2

Comment: The exception you've shown is from EF6, not EF Core.

Comment: Really? What makes you say that? Nuget package manager shows I am using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore v3.1.9

Comment: `System.Data.Entity.*` namespaces are used by EF6. EF Core namespaces start with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`. Also the `SqlQuery` method (no such method exists in EF Core). Etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels like a cludge,
I added

```
 ,null as job
```

to the last select statement

Comment: do the same for a calculated field

Comment: or change the field into a method.